# Let $X$ be a Random Variable. Define $2X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to know what exactly the changes are in the values the random variable($2X$) can take, if for example $X$ follows a Poisson or Binomial Distribution.

If suppose $X$ follows a Poisson distribution with a mean $\lambda$, then we know that $X$ can be any whole number.
So what about $2X$ then? Will it also take values that are all whole numbers or only positive even numbers?
Also, what would be the probability density function for $2X$.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a discrete distribution, $$P(2X=n)=P(X=n/2),$$ so it will be $0$ for odd $n$ and for $n=2k$ you get $P(2X=n)=P(X=k)$. For a continuous distribution, $$P(|2X-x|<\epsilon)=P(|X-x/2|<\epsilon/2),$$ so if the probability distribution function of $X$ is $f_X$, the probability distribution function of $2X$ is $$f_{2X}(x)=\frac12f_X\left(\frac x2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a 1-1 correspondence between the values of $X$ and the values of $2X$. You are correct in saying that $2X$ only assumes values that are twice the values that $X$ assumes. So,if the possible values of $X$ are $1,2,3,\ldots$, then the possible values of $2X$ are $2,4,6,\ldots$. The PDF (probability density function) of $2X$ looks exactly like that of $X$, except you have changed the labels on the horizontal axis. If you write $Y\equiv 2X$, this means $$f_Y(y) = f_X(\tfrac y2)$$
Here the "interesting" values of $y$ are $2,4,6,\ldots$. Just as $f_X$ is zero away from the values of $X$ where there are point masses, so $f_Y$ is zero away from the values of $Y$ where there are point masses.